# How to set website cookies for 3rd party site?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, network-security

I am new to Network Security, I tried to learn a bit about 3rd party cookies. I by now know that 3rd party cookies are not allowed in updated browser due to Same origin policy (which enhances secuirty), you can't read/cookies to cross domain.

My question is that when I visit some site, I can see that cookies from different domains are set. I tried to do this manually on local host, but could not do it. You can see the image below shows that 16 cookies from other sites are set, and I am not getting how is this done.

Kindly clear it, and put some sample code which I could run on my local host.

Thanks alot

The [image]

Comment: Are you asking how to implement (for want of a better word) third party cookies?

Comment: I want to know how these 16 cookies from other websites are set. Even facebook is in the list, which does even allow itself to open in an iframe